# Add Materials-UI to Spring + thymeleaf project

Tags: css, material-design, thymeleaf

I would like to add this material to my project in Springboot  +thymeleaf
https://getmdl.io
I've been copied material.min.css to resources/static/css and material.min.js to /resources/static scripts.

In administration.html a added :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{css/material.min.css}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" />
<script src="scripts/material.min.js" th:src="@{scripts/material.min.js}" type="text/javascript"/>
```

But when I use input type par example,  the UI is not animated. How can I do it works. Or there is anoter good materials to used with thymeleaf ?

Comment: What is Component you using ? what is message you get in console window?

Comment: no messages in console . I am trying to use text field

Comment: see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42528913/3629732)

Comment: I  was trying. The same result. I was added to dependency bower version. there is important that I use  Spring Boot ?

Comment: wait no need dependency bower version , what build tool using? Ex gradle or maven

Comment: Maven.   I ve'ben localize the  error.  When I  added this text field to "main" form  it's works correctly. But when I reload only one div in my form ( via jquery)  when this material is located it doesnt work. Any idea ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am also facing same issue after add WebJar version of material design lite  Maven

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
            <artifactId>material-design-lite</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

(at the time 1.3.0 is latest version)

```
 <script src="webjars/material-design-lite/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
```

instead of

```
<script src="scripts/material.min.js" th:src="@{scripts/material.min.js}" type="text/javascript"/>
```

Note:

In `<body>` tag all page contents(Cards,Labels,Navigation Bar) with in container `<div>` tag

```
<div class="container">
//All page contents kept here 
</div>
```

Comment: if I dont use npm or bower but pure thymeleaf which version for maven do i download ?

Comment: I ve'ben localize the error. When I added this text field to "main" form it's works correctly. But when I reload only one div in my form ( via jquery) where this material is located it doesnt work. Any idea ?

Comment: @VANILKA Which Version Spring boot using ?

Comment: @VANILKA Check answer now

Comment: but now I have  my page like this. But when I click on button on div 1.  I reload this div with content of  "template-div-3". And in template-div-3  it doesnt works.  When I  added template-div-3 directly on load page. It will be work.     But I neet to reload divs without reload all page

Comment: @VANILKA This issue is solved right accept and ask as new question

Comment: I think that not yet.   In loaded divs  materials still not  loaded.

Comment: I think that I found the problem. But I still  dont know how resolve it. When I  write in console componentHandler.upgradeDom();  it works.  But in my Methods I don't know where I must add this method. After $('id-of-element').load("somethink"); it didn't work